# How do I install requirements in Go? "cannot find package"

Tags: go

I'm new to Go and I'm trying to set up a Go project with minimal documentation: https://github.com/alphagov/metadata-api

I've cloned it, but when I try `go build` I get the following warnings:

```
main.go:8:2: cannot find package "github.com/Sirupsen/logrus" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.3.3/libexec/src/pkg/github.com/Sirupsen/logrus (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/me/go/src/github.com/Sirupsen/logrus (from $GOPATH)
main.go:14:2: cannot find package "github.com/alphagov/metadata-api/content_api" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.3.3/libexec/src/pkg/github.com/alphagov/metadata-api/content_api (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/me/go/src/github.com/alphagov/metadata-api/content_api (from $GOPATH)
```

I'm guessing this is because I haven't installed the Go equivalent of requirements?

My `GOPATH` is set:

```
metadata-api$ echo $GOPATH
/Users/me/go
```

And the Go executable is in

```
metadata-ape$ echo $PATH
....:/Users/me/go/bin
```

What do I need to do to help Go find these packages?

Comment: Update: I added Go to my path `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/anna/go` and now `go build` does not produce any errors... but nor does it seem to generate anything.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You should install package first:

try

```
$ go get github.com/Sirupsen/logrus
```

and check you `$GOPATH` dir

This project use [`gom`](https://github.com/mattn/gom) as the package manager,

Make sure you have installed `gom`

or try this command

```
$ gom install
```

I think your `$GOPATH` and `$PATH` settings are incorrect, the `$GOPATH` environment variable specifies the location of your workspace, these are my path settings:

```
export GOROOT=$HOME/bin/go
export GOBIN=$GOROOT/bin
export GOPATH=$HOME/golang
export PATH=$PATH:$GOBIN
```

Comment: Thanks. `gom install` seems to be doing the trick, but how did you know this project used `gom`?

Comment: I also tried simly `go get` and I think it got all of my dependencies at the same time.

Comment: $GOPATH environment variable specifies the location of your workspace? Does that mean i have to export all of these variables everytime i create a new workspace-project?

Comment: This is the closest to the answer and provides the correct directions to reach the fix, other answers should not be approached. But it is important to specify, why we are doing this.
- GO has a concept of WORKSPACE, so whenever we do `go build` , the go compiler will search for the two `environment` variables, `GOPATH` and `GOROOT` to find the `src` path to compile the package and generate the binaries 
- So do we always need to have a `WORKSPACE` set, yes. Unless.... you would want to stuff everything (meaning every package) in the `GOPATH`  or

read - https://go.dev/doc/gopath_code

Comment: The `gom` project is now archived.

Answer (score 51):

I had similar issue and

```
export GO111MODULE=on
```

helped.

Comment: This is what I needed too. Went looking for why - here's a rundown: https://dev.to/maelvls/why-is-go111module-everywhere-and-everything-about-go-modules-24k

Comment: Just spent way too long trying to figure out why. Thank you for this!!!

Comment: You saved my life.

Answer (score 5):

When you need your code to do something that might have been implemented by someone else (in Github or a package somewhere else), You should initialize a go mod file inside of your folder.)

For the purposes of this example, I'll just use example.com/module.

```
go mod init example.com/module
```

Add new module requirements and sums:

```
go mod tidy
```

Run your program:

```
go run .
```

For more details, see https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/getting-started.

Answer (score 3):

Was able to fix the similar issue in Go 1.13.7 by typing:

```
 export GOPATH=~/go
 go get github.com/profile/repository 
 (e.g. github.com/Sirupsen/logrus)
```

Answer (score 0):

["...Starting in Go 1.13, module mode will be the default for all development..."](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules)

["...When using modules, GOPATH is no longer used for resolving imports. However, it is still used to store downloaded source code (in GOPATH/pkg/mod) and compiled commands (in GOPATH/bin)..."](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-GOPATH_and_Modules)