# How to execute the "make-all" command inside go-ethereum?

Tags: go, ubuntu, makefile, blockchain, go-ethereum

I've downloaded Go-Ethereum to develop an Ethereum App to process dummy transactions to understand the flow of Cryptocurrency.

Now, I've been trying to execute the "make all" command from the go-etherium directory to build the target files but I'm still getting errors even after I've set the path correctly in the .bashrc file. I'm getting the error: make: *** [Makefile:21: all] Error 1

What should I do to make this work?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Following is the screenshot of the same:-

[image]

Note:- The OS I'm using here is Ubuntu.

Here is the complete error in text form:

```
shashankk@Shashankk:~/go-ethereum$ make all
env GO111MODULE=on go run build/ci.go install
build/ci.go:61:2: cannot find package "github.com/cespare/cp" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/cespare/cp (from $GOROOT)
    /home/shashankk/go/src/github.com/cespare/cp (from $GOPATH)
build/ci.go:62:2: cannot find package "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto/signify" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto/signify (from $GOROOT)
    /home/shashankk/go/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto/signify (from $GOPATH)
build/ci.go:63:2: cannot find package "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/internal/build" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/internal/build (from $GOROOT)
    /home/shashankk/go/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/internal/build (from $GOPATH)
build/ci.go:64:2: cannot find package "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/params" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/params (from $GOROOT)
    /home/shashankk/go/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/params (from $GOPATH)
make: *** [Makefile:21: all] Error 1
shashankk@Shashankk:~/go-ethereum$
```

Answer (score 1):

You should move the repo to `~/go/src/github.com/ethereum/`.

For Go, GitHub repo should clone to `$GOPATH/src/github.com/${USERNAME}/${REPO_NAME}`.

The default value of `$GOPATH` is `~/go`.

See https://golang.org/doc/gopath_code#Organization

Answer (score 0):

I think this has most likely something to do with your Golang environment variables rather than with go-ethereum, see [How do I install requirements in Go? "cannot find package"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27249420/how-do-i-install-requirements-in-go-cannot-find-package).

Besides that, I just want to note that you can also install go-ethereum just via PPAs on Ubuntu described in the [docs](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/install-and-build/installing-geth):

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ethereum
```

You can also replace `ethereum` with `ethereum-unstable` for the developer version.